# Create multiple text files based on existing files

Tags: for-loop, cmd

I have a large number of existing files. I want to create new text files that include the name of the existing files plus some additional text and then names the file with a different extension based on the original file name. I can use command or powershell.

For example.

**Current filenames**

123.yuv

456.yuv

**Content in new (separate) files**

123.yuv Hello World123

456.yuv Hello World546

**New filenames**

123.avs

456.avs

What I've tried: I created this simple code that puts all the output into a single file. I can then go through some gyrations to create separate files. But it would be easier to just create the separate files straight away. I've researched but was not able to figure it out.

```
(for %i in (*.yuv) do @echo %i Hello world%i) > "%~ni.avs"
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code should accomplish what you desire:

```cmd
for %i in ("*.yuv") do > "%~ni.avs" echo/%~i Hello World%~ni
```

Since in your code you placed parentheses around the whole `for` loop, the redirection `>` happens outside of the loop context, hence the loop variable `%~ni` is not available.